# How to find height for non-binary tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, height

So I am struggling with writing a recursive method for finding height for a tree. This each tree node has a list of children. My code returns exception because `max` somehow is an empty sequence. Could someone provide a valid one?

```
def height(t):
    """
    Return 1 + length of longest path of t.

    @param Tree t: tree to find height of
    @rtype: int

    >>> t = Tree(13)
    >>> height(t)
    1
    >>> t = descendants_from_list(Tree(13), [0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13], 3)
    >>> height(t)
    3
    """
    # 1 more edge than the maximum height of a child, except
    # what do we do if there are no children?
    if t.children is None:
        return 1

    else:
        return 1+max(height(x) for x in t.children)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please : )

Answer (score 5):

I guess the `t.children` is an *empty* list  - `[]` - on leaf nodes, not `None`.

```
>>> [] is None
False
>>> not []
True
```

`max` cannot be used with empty iterables - what do you imagine would be the maximum value in `[]`, 0 or -∞, or 42?

Just test with `if not t.children:`:

```
if not t.children:
    return 1

else:
    return 1 + max(height(x) for x in t.children)
```

Comment: +1 This helped me figure out how to compute the parse tree height of a spaCy dependency parse. (Commenting here so people can maybe find this q/a by searching those terms.